# Remove the new debug levels in salesforce - Winter 16 update

Tags: debug, winter16

Does anyone know how to remove the new debug levels which are recently released in winter 16 update?

Comment: Confusing question, do you mean filtering?

Comment: I was testing with this debug logs and trace flags with recent winter 16 update and created 3 new debug levels, one for  each user trace flag. I wanted to deleted that debug levels. How?

Comment: I haven't messed with the new winter debug logs yet

Comment: Change Log Levels | Click the Add/Change button, then highlight the custom level and click Remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Developer Console

```
Change Log Levels | Add/change | Highlight custom level | Remove
```